# Use Photoshop Custom JavaScript to Stop Actions Panel Playback

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have recorded an action set using the Photoshop Actions Panel. One of the steps is a custom javascript. At the end of the javascript, a test is preformed. If passed, the *action* should continue. If failed, the *action* should stop. I'm not talking about a simple `return` statement within the javascript. **I want the equivalent of `Actions > Insert Stop` in javascript form**. Is this possible?

```
#target photoshop

if (documents.length != 0)
{
    // app.actionsPanel.stop();
}
```

Comment: I've never seen anything that would make me think this is do-able.  Maybe someone can prove me wrong?? Is there some reason you don't just make the entire thing a script?  I find that generally works much better than trying to pass control back and forth.  You can kick another action off from a script - so your other option would be to split the action into two and only kick off the second action if your criteria is met.

Comment: @AnnaForrest Thanks for the suggestions. I wish a hack wasn't required. Strange this is, I think we can do the opposite and `executeAction`s.